# How to build ffmpeg as a Position independent executable (PIE) or PIC on Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have checked out the latest source of ffmpeg from the official website. I now want to compile and build  ffmpeg as a position independent executable.

Here is what my configure command looks like

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-pic --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
```

I have added the option `--enable-pic` to make it a PIE. However when the build process completes successfully and when I do a hardening check as follows then I get below output

hardening-check ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg:
Position Independent Executable: no, normal executable!
Stack protected: yes
Fortify Source functions: yes (some protected functions found)
Read-only relocations: yes
Immediate binding: no, not found!
```

This tells me that ffmpeg is still not a PIE. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? Is there any other changes that need to be done for adding PIE support.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add -fPIE and -pie options to CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to the configure script like the following :

```
./configure <other options> \
 --extra-cflags="-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIE -pie" \
 --extra-ldflags="-L../x264 -fPIE -pie"
```

The latest scripts have these changes already.

Comment: -fPIE is only for cflags, and -pie is only for ldflags

Answer (score 0):

don't confuse PIE and PIC, sepecially in your params and pass -pie to your linker options - PIC is for shared libraries and NOT executeables

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Harden_All_Packages

Comment: i understand the difference now thanks.. but how do I add support the PIE support to my ffmpeg